# Can I call a custom class in the cakephp framework

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakePHP,

I have write a class in MODEL with name of myClass() and I have one function like func().

**CODE:**

```
class myClass(){
    function func(){
        echo "test";
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to call the "myClass class" and run the function func() in the controller file in the cakePHP framework.

Answer (score 2):

Of-course you can http://book.cakephp.org/view/943/Loading-Vendor-Files

```
App::import('Vendor', 'myClass');
$class = new myClass();
```

Comment: Note that 1.3 introduces a `libs` directory to the [folder structure](http://book.cakephp.org/view/899/CakePHP-Folder-Structure) that can be used for your own libraries, to keep them separate from any 3rd party libraries in the `vendors` directory.